# Strange behavior of child UL on father LI's animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/RedKnight91/Z6Ueu/4/

Hi! Look at that last menu (on the bottom). When you hover on one of the LIs with the "+" symbol, that have a children UL, which is a submenu, the slideToggle shows the child UL, but when the animation finishes, it changes width.

I can see it better on chrome.

What could the problem be?

Here's the code:

HTML

```
<ul class="vertical extend color">
        <li class="father">Uova
            <ul>
                <li>Fresche</li>
                <li>Di terra</li>
                <li>Artificiali</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>burro</li>
        <li class="father">zuppa
            <ul>
                <li>di legumi</li>
                <li>di ceci</li>
                <li>di fagioli</li>
                <li>fredda</li>
                <li>calda</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>limone</li>
        <li>Acqua</li>
    </ul>
```

CSS

```
ul{ padding:0; margin: 0; list-style-type: none; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight:bold; }

        li{ background: #EEE; box-shadow: 0 1px 10px #777; padding:5px; margin:0; width:150px; cursor: pointer; text-align: center; text-shadow: 1px 2px 0 white; position: relative; }
        li:hover{ background-color:#333; color:white; text-shadow: 1px 2px 0 black; }

        ul.horizontal{ display: inline; }
        ul.horizontal li { display:inline-block; zoom: 1; *display:inline; }

        ul.vertical li { margin:1px; }

        ul.extend > li:hover { background-color: #EEE; }

        li.father { padding: 5px 10px 0 0; }
        li.father ul { margin-left: -1px; display: none; padding: 0; }
        li.father:hover li { background-color:#EEE; color: #AAA; text-shadow: 1px 2px 0 white; }
        li.father:before { content: "+"; color: #555;}
        li.father:hover:before { content: "-"; color: #FFF;}​
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(function(){

            $("li.father").hover(
                function(){
                    $(this).find("ul").stop().slideToggle(400);
                },
                function(){
                    $(this).find("ul").stop().slideToggle(400);
                }
            );

            $("ul.extend li").not(".father").hover(
                function(){
                    $(this).animate({width:"170"}, {duration:200, queue:false});
                },
                function(){
                    $(this).animate({width: "150"}, {duration:500, easing: "easeOutBounce", queue:false});
                }
            );

            $("ul.color li").hover(
                function(){
                    $(this).animate({backgroundColor: "#333"}, {duration:100, queue:false});
                },
                function(){
                    $(this).animate({backgroundColor: "#EEE"}, {duration:100, queue:false});
                }
            );
        });​
```

Comment: Please include relevant code in your question too! A demo is great as enhancement but not sufficient on its own (what if jsfiddle is down for some reason?).

Comment: Well, I've never seen jsFiddle down, but ok, I'll now add the code. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this happens because you specified

```
li.father { padding: 5px 10px 0 0; }
```

so, also the nested ul has that padding. Just remove the right padding and increment the size of  `li.father` by 10 pixel, like so

```
li.father { padding: 5px 0 0 0; width: 160px; }
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/Z6Ueu/9/

Comment: Oh, perfect! But why did it get the padding only at the end of the slideToggle? Is that slideToggle's default behavior?

Comment: I couldn't say exactly the slideToggle behaviour, but probably a display property changes at the end of the animation (or some padding collapse)